# Custom Elements: Access the property of another element

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element, lit-html, lit

I am using Lit Custom Elements:

I am using component A in my component B and want to access the property letters of B (from child to parent element). How do I do that?

```
// Component A
@customElement('a-component')
class AComponent extends LitElement {
  @property() public letters = ['a', 'b', 'c' ]
  //.....


// Component B
// ...
   <a-component id="a"></add-photo-component>
//....
```

Comment: If you don't have shadowRoot boundaries in between, ``this.closest("b-component")`` should work fine

Comment: I can have the whole component returned with  ```this.shadowRoot?.querySelector('#a-component');```, but how can I access the property value of this?

Comment: This is what you get when people learn Tools (Goole's Lit) _**before**_ learning the core Technology (Web Components; by Microsoft,Apple,Mozilla & Google). Ditch Lit (all bells and whistles), play with native Technology for a week (or so), so you learn, and understand WHAT you are doing. Then pick any of the 58 Tools that make developing Web Components "easier" ... or continue with Native Technology (that will last another 27 JavaScript years without requiring any update). Oh, and go find someone who experienced the Google Angular 1 to Google Angular 2 Update, and ask them what that was like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using component A in my component B and want to access the property letters of B (from child to parent element). How do I do that?

**Simple answer: You don't.** At least not in that direction. If component A needs to know letters, have component B pass it into A via properties or attributes.

### Here's why:

Your thought concept is problematic because it violates the basic idea of components. Components are meant to encapsulate what they do; a child component is never meant to access components outside of its own scope (including any parent components). A component should not know anything about its context (that is, their parent or any other ancestors, except those always present (e.g. `document.body`, and even those should only be accessed if your component is *connected*, which you can always check via the boolean built-in-property `this.isConnected`)). This concept is called *de-coupling* and is widely considered the architectural go-to-standard in a componentized world.

Otherwise you are sort of hard-wiring your component to that context, making it either useless or throw errors when you want to re-use that component in other contexts.

If there is anything that comes from outside and the component needs to know about it (e.g. data), then pass that to the child component via properties or attributes.

If interaction with the child component cannot be handled by the component itself, inform the outside world about it via custom events. In that case it would be any of the ancestor components' job to pick up on this (it would then have a listener for that event), and do something with it, and if the result of that is supposed to affect that child component, then pass it into that component, again via properties or attributes, or by e.g. calling a callback that might have been part of the custom event data the child component had issued.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! Sorry! I meant that data should be transferred from the child element to the parent. So the access should be from parent element to the data (property) of the child element

Comment: I would do that using events to prevent unnecessary coupling of the components, meaning the parent component shouldn't throw any errors if the child component isn't present, *unless it creates this child component*. How does the child component know its data is needed? Do you have a user-interaction that causes this?

Comment: Exactly, when a button is pressed, data is generated in the child component and this data should then be transferred to the parent component.

Comment: Then create a [custom event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent), and dispatch it on `this`. You can pass data in the `event.detail` property. The parent element then needs to set up a listener on that custom event.

Comment: Make sure to set `composed: true` on that custom event if components further up in the ancestor tree need to also catch the event. With `composed: false` - which is the default - custom events cannot pass shadow DOM boundaries.